# JHTML calender show error when change format in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am facing a facing a problem with JHTMl calender method. Here is my code what I am trying to do:

**edit.php**

```
$this->event->from_date="2013-11-20 5:10:00";
$from_date = explode(" ", $this->event->from_date);

$from_time12 = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($from_date[0]));

echo JHTML::_('calendar', $from_time12, 'from_date', 'from_date', '%m-%d-%Y', array('class' => 'required', 'size' => '15', 'onchange' => 'getfromdate(this.value)'));
```

It's working fine for new item but when i edit the existing item it's shows error :

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (10-22-2013) at
>   position 0 (1): Unexpected character

I don't understand what's the problem. If anyone has suggestion please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding where is the problem**

Generally problems are solved by understanding the error messages. In this case DateTime complains that it cannot parse the string `10-22-2013`, which is rather normal because this format is not accepted by `DateTime`. When in doubt don't forget to check the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). Investing a couple of hours in reading this stuff saves you in the future lots of time.

**Fixing the code**

For example, to get back to your error, try formatting the date as `Y-m-d` inside $from_time12.

**Improving the code**

Also the conversions that you are doing there are rather confusing...  Not only can `strtotime` parse directly strings like `2013-11-20 5:10:00`, but also DateTime can also understand it. So you should be able to pass `$this->event->from_date` directly to `JHTML::_('calendar'...`) replacing `$from_time12` instead of doing tons of conversions.